# SQL include Record with AND/OR/BOTH

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a set of fields that the user can choose to narrow down search results. The last two selections are check boxes, Please let me know if I should change this once I have described the problem.

I have a list of items with two options A and B. These are flagged in the database as 0 for no and 1 for yes. These options can be flagged on one, the other, or both.

```
Item 1 (0,1)
Item 2 (1,1)
Item 3 (1,0)
```

I would like to retrieve item 2 and 3 if the user checks the first box.
I would like to retrieve item 1 and 2 if the user checks the second box.
I would like to retrieve all items if they check both boxes.

I think I need to do something like:

```
WHERE (A = check1 AND ( B = 0 OR B = 1 )) 
  AND (B = check2 AND ( A = 0 OR A = 1 ))
```

But it is not working. With check 1 checked, I only get Item 3, and not Item 2 and 3.

Comment: You can change the condition based on the checkbox and just check if the selected one is `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
where (check1 = 0 or A = 1) and (check2 = 0 or B = 1)
```

Your "0" for the check boxes means everything, so include that in the logic.

Comment: Thanks, this isn't the exact solution I am going to use but pointing out that the "0" is important was something I was not even thinking about. Thanks for the tips!